# Publish front page in Wordpress without the slug "home"

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, slug

I have a front page with the slug "home," It works just fine if I go to `www.mydomain.com/home`. I'm getting "Page not found" for `www.mydomain.com`. I want to remove the slug "home" from my page so that I will be able to see it on `www.mydomain.com`.
I've tried to go to `customize -> Homepage settings` and set my page as a static page, but it didn't work. I also tried to go to `Settings-> Reading` and define it from there. How can I make it works?

Comment: What did you define for your settings in the Reading settings?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign your page from here:

> Settings->Reading

and then you can see the

> Home Page Displays

section. In this section you need to select the **A Static Page(Select Below)** option. In the dropdown you need to select the value **Home** (the page you would like to display as the Home page display).

After making changes you can click on the Save button.

[screenshot for reference]: [image: Screenshot for reference]